Uploading shiny app to shiny io fails due to homebrew warning
I am trying to upload a shiny app that runs in my Mac to shiny io. The process works well right up until I get the following error:
Configuration failed because libarchive was not found. Try installing:

deb: libarchive-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
rpm: libarchive-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
csw: libarchive_dev (Solaris)
brew: libarchive (Mac OSX)
If libarchive is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libarchive.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'



installing to library ‘/usr/lib/R’
installing source package ‘archive’ ...
** package ‘archive’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
:1:10: fatal error: archive.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘archive’
removing ‘/usr/lib/R/archive’

I checked using "brew ls" that libarchive is indeed installed. So I imagine the problem lies with the pkg-config not being in my PATH and/or the PKG_CONFIG_PATH not containing a libarchive.pc.file. But I have no idea what the PATH is, or how to find said PATH in my MAC, let alone what it means by the PKG_CONFIG_PATH. I have searched online but have been unable to find a solution, so any help would be much appreciated - if possible one that would be as simple as possible given my lack of knowledge.

This message is coming from the server, not your own machine. Per https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/issues/358 the libarchive system dependency isn't currently supported on shinyapps so {archive} can't be installed. As a workaround, you could see whether there are some alternative packages that don't have that dependency that would achieve the same result.
